# Optional vector of type CV_8U and size <number _of_variables_in_samples> + <number_of_variables_in_responses>

Tags: c#, opencv, machine-learning, emgucv

I am trying to load TrainData in EmguCV and everything works fine for numerical data without specifying the varType parameter.
I want to load TrainData such that all inputs are numerical and all labels are categorical. To specify the data type to be either numerical or categorical Emgucv has Enum EmguCV.ML.MlEnum.varType.Numerical or .Categorical which I am unable to use in the current situation.

```
using (TrainData td = new TrainData(trainData, Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.DataLayoutType.RowSample,trainClasses,null,null,null,?))
            {
                nnet.SetLayerSizes(layerSizeMat);
                nnet.SetActivationFunction(ANN_MLP.AnnMlpActivationFunction.SigmoidSym, 0.6, 1);
                nnet.TermCriteria = new MCvTermCriteria(430, 1.0e-8);
                nnet.SetTrainMethod(ANN_MLP.AnnMlpTrainMethod.Backprop, 0.3, 0);
                try
                {
                    nnet.Train(td, (int)Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.AnnMlpTrainingFlag.Default);
                    Console.WriteLine("Training Completed Successfully....");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Training Error:" + e.Message);
                }
            }
```

[image: Emgucv TrainData varType]

It requires Optional vector of type CV_8U and size  + , containing types of each input and output variable.

Can someone explain me the meaning of the above line and how can I create a vector of type CV_8U in EmguCv C#.
for the example of the MNIST Dataset with 784 input columns and 1 output column with 10 categorical values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emgucv Github Repository AutoTestML.cs](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/blob/master/Emgu.CV.Test/AutoTestML.cs)
 
has a test case which explains what was required. Following is the code snippet:

```
Matrix<Byte> varType = new Matrix<byte>(data.Cols + 1, 1);
varType.SetValue((byte) MlEnum.VarType.Numerical); //the data is numerical
varType[data.Cols, 0] = (byte) MlEnum.VarType.Categorical; //the response is catagorical
// .....
using (TrainData td = new TrainData(data, MlEnum.DataLayoutType.RowSample, response, null, null, null, varType))
```